# Is there a built in enum that represents an Arc or Weak, similar to Cow?

Tags: rust

Is there a builtin enum that can contain either an `Arc<T>` or a `Weak<T>` similar to how `Cow<T>` can either contain an owned or borrowed value? I've used this pattern several times, and I'm wondering if I should just (internally) formalise my own enum or if this already exists.

Is something similar to the following pseudo-rust already defined?

```
pub enum MaybeWeak<T> {
  Strong(Arc<T>),
  Weak(Weak<T>),
}

impl<T> MaybeWeak<T> {
  pub fn try_deref(&self) -> Option<Arc<T>> {
    match self {
      Strong(a) => Some(a.clone()),
      Weak(w) => w.upgrade(),
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing in std, apparently because it is not that common. But you can easily build your own, with all the functionality you need.

Comment: But, depending on your use case, maybe holding `Option<Arc>` and `upgrade()`ing early will work for you and be better.

Comment: Had the same idea today where I needed to initialize a channel inside of the type, but then eventually I wanted to give away the sender (tx) and not hold strong ownership of it anymore inside of the type. But to be fair this seems a bit esoteric.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is. It's called `Weak`.

`Arc` (or `Rc` for that matter) doesn't represent an *owned* value (that's `Box`) but a shared value that you have a shared reference to. If you don't know whether this value exist or not, that's what `Weak` represent. Your `MaybeWeak` enum doesn't make much sense. Just store a `Weak` and call `upgrade` on it, when you want to access the value.

And on the other hand prefer fully qualified notation `Arc::clone(&ptr)` and `Weak::upgrade(&ptr)` over calling it using dot operator to avoid potential errors when `T` has methods with the same name.

Comment: The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I have a field that may or may not contain a strong reference to a value. For all intents and purposes, the code is agnostic as to whether it actually has a strong reference - it's up to the user of the code if it should keep a strong reference or not. So I need some way to transparently store a value that may or may not be a strong reference.

Comment: @A.Z. Is your goal actually to dynamically vary between strong and weak reference semantics? `MaybeWeak` will prevent the object from getting dropped if it's `Strong` but not if it's `Weak`. *If* that's your goal, I think what you have is the best option and the first part of this answer is wrong, though the last paragraph is still valid.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm implementing a dynamic event that has two types of subscribers: weak ones, which have a guard returned to the caller, and permanent ones that will remain subscribed forever. I'd like to contain the references for the guarded and permanent callbacks in the same list to reduce complexity.

Comment: @A.Z. I still think that `Weak` is conceptually something that *may* be a strong reference. And I don't see how it's different from what you are saying. Could you edit your question and provide a broader example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Nevermind. I get it now. And I think I must agree with Solomon, your solution is probably the best you could do.